# How to keep the particles.js interaction while below other elements

Tags: javascript, html, css, particle.js

I am using [particle.js](http://vincentgarreau.com/particles.js/) as a background. I have managed to place on the background with use of z-index. I tried a suggestion on the github isseus page. The z-index and this:

```
"interactivity": {
    "detect_on": "canvas",
```

This bit was already added in the default particle configuration.

The problem is similar as: [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40720838/particles-js-as-a-background). He said he solved it but looking at his codepen link it doesnt seem the same. There is no content above the the particles.

Mine current build: [Github](https://github.com/elron1010/portfolio/tree/develop)
PROBLEM = the interactivity works just above the first content box and just below it. 
I have tried multiple edits with the width of elements and z-index. Also tried using a extra div for the other content.

How can I get the interactivity to work on the sides?

Answer (score 13):

Try this in your html

```
<div id="particles-js" style="position:fixed;width:100%;z-index:-10;"></div>
```

Also if you want interactive controls while particles are in the background

set **interactivity** to **window** instead of **canvas** in *particles.json* file

```
"interactivity": {
"detect_on": "window",
```

Comment: edit: set `position:absolute;` and also set `height:100vh;`

Comment: can use `width: 100vw;` for consistency.

Answer (score 1):

[I exported from this codepen initially](https://codepen.io/samarkandiy/pen/xGEOLN)

And then I changed his css:

```
canvas {
width: 100%;
height:100%;
}

h1{
margin: 0 auto;
text-align: center;
width: 100%;
font-size: 2rem;
padding-top: 20rem;
font-weight: 200;
z-index: 2;
}

#particles-js {
position: absolute;
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
background-colour: #000000;
z-index: -1 !important; 
}
```

In the html:

```
<body>
<div id="particles-js"></div>
<h1> My text for my overlay title </h1>
```

In the index.js around line 73 of the export change the "detect_on" part from canvas to window regarding interactivity:

```
"detect_on": "window",
```

[working example of above](http://www.massgeeks.com)

There is another codepen set and working demo solving the same issue here [other working code example](http://codepen.io/aaronms/pen/XEYamz) but you get to see less of the other options to edit where I changed dots to stars etc.